# logrotate file with prerotate

Tags: file, unix, logging, logrotate

I create a logrotate for test.log file

```
/var/log/test.log /var/log/test.log.a /var/log/test.log.b{
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    delaycompress
    create 640 root root
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
            /root/script.sh /var/log/test.log
    endscript}
```

In prerorate I insert command for create test.log.a test.log.b, but when I see result of rotate, only file rotated is /var/log/test.log.

I want create two file first of rotate and rotate it with test.log.

Is possible??

Thanks in advance
Dario

Comment: Can you update your post with the contents of `/root/script.sh`?  Your end curly bracket should be on the next line, but perhaps just a typo.  Your logrotate rule looks ok to me, if I'm understanding what you want correctly.  It should do this:
1) on the first run create `test.log.a` and `test.log.b` (via `script.sh`), then rotate test.log (so test.log.1 will be created)
2) on the second run, run `script.sh` again, then rotate `test.log`, `test.log.a` and `test.log.b`.  `test.log.1` would be compressed and becomes `test.log.2.gz`.
Is this what you want?

Comment: Hi, script do also create file test.log.a and test.log.b.
I want, after create test.log.a and test.log.b rotate all three file (test.log, test.lob.a and test.log.b) at the same time.

Comment: it should do that, it worked for me, but I'm not exactly sure what your `script.sh` file does besides creating files `test.log.a` and `test.log.b`.  If you post what's in that script, I'll try and help you figure out why it isn't working for you.

Comment: `#!/bin/bash
cp $1 /var/log/test.log.a
cp $1 /var/log/test log.b`

this is **script.sh**